# How do I create an aws Comprehend endpoint thru terraform?

Tags: terraform, endpoint, amazon-comprehend

I have an aws Comprehend text classifier trained. I would like to set up an endpoint for it, but by using terraform and not the console.

I noticed that there are *sagemaker* endpoints in terraform, like this:

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_endpoint_configuration" "ec" {
  name = "my-endpoint-config"

  production_variants {
    variant_name           = "variant-1"
    model_name             = aws_sagemaker_model.m.name
    initial_instance_count = 1
    instance_type          = "ml.t2.medium"
  }
}
```

but Comprehend is a different service and has no such analogous statement. I was hoping to find something like
`resource "aws_comprehend_endpoint_configuration"`
but nothing like this exists

How do I create an aws Comprehend endpoint thru terraform?